# Counting Values in Multidimensional Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know this question has already been answered a few times, however, none of the answers apply to my scenario.

Current Array:

```
    Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1AM
            [1] => 2AM
            [2] => 3AM
            [3] => 4AM
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1AM
            [1] => 2AM
            [2] => 6AM
            [3] => 4AM
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1AM
            [1] => 2AM
            [2] => 7AM
            [3] => 4AM
        )

)
```

Desired Output:

```
3 People Signed Up at 1AM,

3 People signed up at 2AM,

1 Signed up at 3AM

1 Signed up at 6AM

1 Signed up at 7AM

3 Signed up at 4AM
```

Current code:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = array_count_values($v);
    arsort($result[$k]);
}
print_r($result);
```

In other words, just counting the times and storing them in a separate array or variable.

Comment: array_count_values(call_user_func_array('merge', $array));

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use `array_count_values` along with `call_user_func_array` like as

```
array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solutions I think

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    $result[] = count($item);
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP >= 5.6 you can use the argument unpacking instead of calling the call_user_func_array():

```
$result = array_count_values(array_merge(...$array));
```

Read more: [Argument unpacking via ...](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)

Answer (score 0):

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'array_key'));
```